# Get only linear models with more than one predictor from list

Tags: r

I have a list of linear models and want to only grab those with more than one predictor.

Here's my example data:

```
require(faraway)
lm1 <- lm(lifespan ~ brain, mammalsleep)
lm2 <- lm(lifespan ~ brain+dream+nondream, mammalsleep)
lm3 <- lm(lifespan ~ brain+sleep, mammalsleep)
lm4 <- lm(lifespan ~ brain+predation+danger, mammalsleep)
lm5 <- lm(lifespan ~ sleep, mammalsleep)

list_models <- list(lm1, lm2, lm3, lm4, lm5)
```

My approach:

```
map(list_models, function(x)if(length(names(x$model))>2){
  list_models
})
```

This approach seems to return far too many models.

Alternatively:

```
true_false <-map(list_models, function(x)length(names(x$model))>2)

models <- mapply(function(x, y)ifelse(y == TRUE, x, 0), list_models, a) %>% keep(~all(. != 0))


[[1]]
(Intercept)       brain       dream    nondream 
23.89600096  0.01637543 -2.87404813 -0.28644022 

[[2]]
 (Intercept)        brain        sleep 
28.446910677  0.007815582 -1.051868346 

[[3]]
  (Intercept)         brain     predation        danger 
 21.364090058   0.008106425 -10.425407458   9.818648866
```

However, these are not saved as linear models (notice the 'Call' is not introduced).

Expected output:

```
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = lifespan ~ brain + dream + nondream, data = mammalsleep)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        brain        dream     nondream  
   23.89600      0.01638     -2.87405     -0.28644  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = lifespan ~ brain + sleep, data = mammalsleep)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        brain        sleep  
  28.446911     0.007816    -1.051868  


[[3]]

Call:
lm(formula = lifespan ~ brain + predation + danger, data = mammalsleep)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        brain    predation       danger  
  21.364090     0.008106   -10.425407     9.818649
```

Comment: What's the point here, why are you estimating models with one predictor in the first place?

Comment: @jay.sf There's no purpose for inference in this, I have built a function that takes a number of permutations on models. I want to graph these with `ellipse` but I need at least two predictors. The models are all stored as a list because there are lots of them.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected, the issue is before the outcome. Better try to adjust this function so that it does not create models with one predictor; should be more efficient. Cheers!

Comment: @jay.sf that would be an option however the original function produces all the models, the separate function is for plotting and it's to be used with respect to the results from the first.

Comment: Feels like you should hack the function :)

Comment: @jay.sf some might say that you're a genius! now that I think about it, I could include an additional parameter to the function to return only models with `x` sized lengths. That way, it would make modelling easier. Either way, both approaches can work. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Very welcome, glad to have given you the right food for thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this one liner get's the job done regardless if a `formula` is used or not.

```
list_models %>% keep(~all(length(names(.$model))>2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would filter on the presence or absence of a "+" in the formula call, e.g.:

```
lm_1term = lm(data=mtcars,mpg~cyl)
lm_2terms = lm(data=mtcars,mpg~cyl+hp)

models = list(lm_1term, lm_2terms)
```

The formula (as a string) is retrievable via

```
as.character(lm_2terms$call)[2]
```

gives us `mpg ~ cyl + hp`, so that we can define a True/False function

```
single_predictor <- function(model) !grepl(as.character(model$call)[2], 
                                           pattern='+', fixed=T)
```

Then you can use `Filter` to select elements from the list:

```
Filter(single_predictor, models)
```

Comment: This works great! a quick question - why does my `mapply` function not return the linear model call but rather a vector?

Comment: On a second thought - this approach would fail if I used a formula for the linear model, because then I would just get from the call `lm(formula=x, data=data`